# What are the allowable characters in identifiers?

Tags: vimscript

In Vim, what characters are allowed in identifiers, such as variable names and function names?

I looked up the help for both variables and functions and neither one defines the allowable character set or syntax for valid identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`:h 41.2`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41.2)

```
*41.2*  Variables

A variable name consists of ASCII letters, digits and the underscore.  It
cannot start with a digit.  Valid variable names are:

    counter
    _aap3
    very_long_variable_name_with_underscores
    FuncLength
    LENGTH

Invalid names are "foo+bar" and "6var".
```

And I think it's the same for functions, note that user defined functions must start with an uppercase letter (except from scriptlocal functions beginning with `s:` as pointed out @D. Ben Knoble in the comments)

Comment: Except scriptlocal `s:` functions, I think

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're right (but even for script local function I like to use the upper case to keep a consistent naming :) )